# phpmyadmin 404 not found on vps

Tags: vps

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on vps. I did everything like here but when i was first installing phpmyadmin in configuration i cancel it (configurarion program with intsalling) now i can't get to work. I got 404 error when i'm going to /phpmyadmin
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04
apache and mysql works but phpmyadmin is not properly configured. Can I do something with that?

Comment: Have you tried http IPaddress:8080? I believe the https followed by domainname will only work if you have configured it. 

Can you please also check if port 8080 is allowed on your firewall?

Comment: Thanks for help, but I already reinstalled ubuntu and i will try once again.